# Python - Creating List Of itertools.permutations That Takes Match Object Output Maxes Physical Memory

Tags: python, pattern-matching, permutation

Here is my code with some notes:

```
import re
import itertools

nouns = ['bacon', 'cheese', 'eggs', 'milk', 'houses', 'dog']
CC = ['and', 'or']

def search_and_replace(text):
    noun_patt = r'\b(' + '|'.join(nouns) + r')\b'
    CC_patt = r'\b(' + '|'.join(CC) + r')\b'
    patt = r'({0},? )+{1} {0}'.format(noun_patt, CC_patt)

    searched = re.search(patt, text) 
    phrase = searched.group()
    print "Check re.search match object exists:", phrase # "bacon, eggs, and milk" prints

    perm_phrase = itertools.permutations(phrase)
    print "Check permutated list exists:", perm_phrase # permutation object position in memory prints

    perm_phrase_list = list(perm_phrase)
    print "Permutated object as list:", perm_phrase_list # THIS IS WHERE MEMORY MAXES AND COMPUTER FREEZES!!!
    # So print does not happen.

    return perm_phrase_list

def main():
    text = "I like bacon, eggs, and milk"
    print search_and_replace(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see from my notes in the code, the line of code `perm_phrase_list = list(perm_phrase)` takes up so much physical memory that my computer freezes. (I printed after each line of code to figure where the problem starts, I wouldn't normally print within a function). I am wondering why this happens at the point of trying to create this list from the permutation?

Will be very convenient if I could use the permutations method in this code! Otherwise, I will just have to create something equivalent for reordering elements in a list.

I am using Python 2.7

Comment: All possible permutations for the characters of the phrase are produced.

Comment: You're not permuting the words; you're generating every possible permutation of the characters. That's not going to work in a reasonable amount of time or space. Are you sure what you want to do makes sense?

Comment: @user2357112 It is actually the words that I want to permutate, so that is where I was confused. Courtesy of the answers below, I suddenly realized that it was the characters that are permutating. I am rewriting my code now to permutate the words instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are feeding a string to `itertools.permutations()`; this means that it'll generate permutations for all possible combinations of the *characters*:

```
>>> phrase = re.search(patt, text).group()
>>> phrase
'bacon, eggs, and milk'
>>> next(itertools.permutations(phrase))
('b', 'a', 'c', 'o', 'n', ',', ' ', 'e', 'g', 'g', 's', ',', ' ', 'a', 'n', 'd', ' ', 'm', 'i', 'l', 'k')
```

Your phrase is 21 characters long, resulting in 21! (factorial) == 51090942171709440000 different permutations; each a tuple of 21 characters.

**One** such tuple takes, on my 64bit Mac, a total of 21 * 38 + 224 bytes = 1022 bytes of memory. The characters are interned, so you really only need to memory per tuple, and can ignore the 768 bytes for the characters. That's then 51090942171709440000 * 224 bytes is almost [10 zebibytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#Specific_units_of_IEC_60027-2_A.2_and_ISO.2FIEC_80000).

That's a whole  lotta memory.

You probably did not want to generate all possible 21-character permutations of the phrase. You need to rethink what you want to do with your method, generate fewer outputs and only loop over the generated combinations one by one, not try to expand all of them into a list object.

I suspect you wanted to create permutations for any of the matched *words*, but your regular expression doesn't give you individual matched words. You cannot repeat capturing groups, you need to capture the *whole*, then split afterwards:

```
noun_patt = r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(nouns) + r')\b'
CC_patt = r'\b(' + '|'.join(CC) + r')\b'
patt = r'((?:{0},? )+){1} ({0})'.format(noun_patt, CC_patt)
```

The `(?:..)` groups are non-capturing groups, to avoid cluttering up our results.

This now gives two capturing groups, one with comma-separated nouns, and one with the last noun. Split the first on whitespace and commas:

```
searched = re.search(patt, text) 
nouns = filter(None, re.split(r',\s*', searched.group(1))) + [searched.group(3)]
```

and *now* you can permute those nouns:

```
for comb in itertools.permutations(nouns):
    # do something with this specific permutation
```

Because your sample results in only 3 nouns, the 6 permutations are safe to turn into a list:

```
>>> nouns
['bacon', 'eggs', 'milk']
>>> list(itertools.permutations(nouns))
[('bacon', 'eggs', 'milk'), ('bacon', 'milk', 'eggs'), ('eggs', 'bacon', 'milk'), ('eggs', 'milk', 'bacon'), ('milk', 'bacon', 'eggs'), ('milk', 'eggs', 'bacon')]
```

We could perhaps re-combine these into sentences:

```
>>> cc = searched.group(2)
>>> for comb in itertools.permutations(nouns):
...     print ', '.join(comb[:-1]), cc, comb[-1]
... 
bacon, eggs and milk
bacon, milk and eggs
eggs, bacon and milk
eggs, milk and bacon
milk, bacon and eggs
milk, eggs and bacon
```

Comment: This is excellent Martijn, thanks. I did solve my original problem by first using the split method to convert the phrase into a list of individual words, so the words not characters permutated. However, you have gone above and beyond to give me exactly what I was looking for! Indeed I did not want permutation variations where the 'and' is anywhere but the 3rd word in the list. Since I wanted to solve my permutation issue first, I had not got as far as how to modify the permutations to get exactly what I need. You correctly inferred what I wanted to do in the bigger picture :-)

Comment: 10 zebibytes - holy mackerel!

Comment: Martijn - I have been racking my brains, trying all sorts of things in my limited newbie repertoire to change the printed output. At the very bottom of your answer, you have printed out all permutations of `bacon, eggs and milk` etc, on newlines. Anyway, for the output is there a way to change it to 1 line as **string** `bacon, eggs and milk*bacon, milk and eggs,*eggs, bacon and milk........`. The '*' as the divide between each permutation.

Comment: Ok, forgot that, with so persistence and study I got it figured out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The line of code `perm_phrase_list = list(perm_phrase)` will attempt to build a list. It may take a lot of memory if it is very large, so you shouldn't do that. To "dump" the result, you should iterate over the generator:

```
for item in perm_phrase: print item #doesn't build the list
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't have any good reason to store all of the values in the list; you can iterate over an iterator just as easily as over a list. So, just return `perm_phrase`. If you just want to print out the values, write something like this:

```
def main():
    text = "I like bacon, eggs, and milk"
    for perm in search_and_replace(text):
        print perm
```

Obviously, you can format things however you want, including adding in the brackets and commas and printing `repr(perm)` to make it look exactly like a list.

By iterating over the iterator, you're only generating one value at a time, instead of all at once, so there's no memory storage problem. (You may also get a speed boost out of "pipelining" the code for each permutation, improving cache hits, etc.)

---

But meanwhile, your question says you want the (4! = 24) permutations of words, rather than the (21! = 51090942171709440000) permutations of characters. To do that, you need to `split` the string into words at some point. For example:

```
perm_phrase = itertools.permutations(phrase.split())
```

Now, you can easily fit those all into memory at once. But you're still better off using an iterator unless you have some good reason to have them all in memory at once.

Comment: Thank you for this super helpful answer. I hadn't thought about actually adding the split into the same line to create the 'perm_phrase' variable. I created a new variable on a new line, so this condensed things and created less code line =)

Comment: @Darren: Well, there's almost no harm in adding one line of code and one intermediate variable, and often it can make this easier to read and/or to debug. So, I didn't really help that much… But learning to convert back and forth between one-liners and separate steps is definitely worth doing.